# Vulkan front face winding order

Tags: c++, vulkan

I configure Vulkan `VkPipelineRasterizationStateCreateInfo`  to use CCW winding order:

```
 VkPipelineRasterizationStateCreateInfo rasterizer = {};
 rasterizer.sType = VK_STRUCTURE_TYPE_PIPELINE_RASTERIZATION_STATE_CREATE_INFO;
 rasterizer.depthClampEnable = VK_FALSE;
 rasterizer.rasterizerDiscardEnable = VK_FALSE;
 rasterizer.polygonMode = VK_POLYGON_MODE_FILL;
 rasterizer.lineWidth = 1.0f;
 rasterizer.cullMode = VK_CULL_MODE_BACK_BIT;
 rasterizer.frontFace = VK_FRONT_FACE_COUNTER_CLOCKWISE;
 rasterizer.depthBiasEnable = VK_FALSE;
```

My assembly state uses triangle fan to draw a quad:

```
  VkPipelineInputAssemblyStateCreateInfo inputAssembly = {};
 inputAssembly.sType = VK_STRUCTURE_TYPE_PIPELINE_INPUT_ASSEMBLY_STATE_CREATE_INFO;
 inputAssembly.topology = VK_PRIMITIVE_TOPOLOGY_TRIANGLE_FAN;
 inputAssembly.primitiveRestartEnable = VK_FALSE;
```

Here is my vertex buffer:

```
 const  VertexPos2Col3 vertices[4] = {
{{0.5f,  0.5f}, {1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f}},
{{-0.5f, 0.5f}, {0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f}},
{{-0.5f, -0.5f}, {0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f}},
{{ 0.5f, -0.5f}, {0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f}}
};
```

The order of the vertices is counter-clock wise. But the primitive shows up only if I set `rasterizer.frontFace = VK_FRONT_FACE_CLOCKWISE;`
Why is that?

System info:

Windows 10, NVIDIA RTX3000, Driver: 431.86

Comment: How about your camera?

Comment: Drawing in NDC space. Use no transformations. Just raw vertex position you see in range   -0.5   ,  0.5

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's because Vulkan uses a different coordinate system than e.g. OpenGL. The origin for Vulkan is top-left.

So you have to cope for that either by changing the vertex/index ordering, by flipping the viewport, or by changing the sing of `gl_position.y` in your vertex shader. If your target supports the `VK_KHR_maintenance1` extensions, then the easiest way would be to [use a negative height](https://www.saschawillems.de/blog/2019/03/29/flipping-the-vulkan-viewport/) to flip the viewport.